# What does "bring a vote to the floor" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I once read in a newspaper the sentence like " some leadership pressed to bring  a vote to the floor on the confirmation of something." So what does the phrase mean here? Any slang used? Where can I look them up? Thanks!

Comment: likeky the Senate Floor

Answer (score 4):

It means take the matter out of a committee and present it to the entire legislative body.

> The **[floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_(legislative))** of a legislature or chamber is the place where members
>   sit and make speeches. When a person is speaking there formally, they
>   are said to *have the floor*. The House of Commons and the House of
>   Lords of the United Kingdom; the U.S. House of Representatives and the
>   U.S. Senate all have "floors" with established procedures and
>   protocols.
>
> ...
>
> Activity on the floor of a council or legislature, such as debate, may
>   be contrasted with meetings and discussion which takes place in
>   committee, for which there are often separate committee rooms.