# What did Jeremy Hunt mean by "slipped" to miss a vote?

Tags: meaning, british-english

Today in the UK House of Commons, Conservative MP and PM candidate Jeremy Hunt failed to take part in an important vote. He [said](https://twitter.com/Jeremy_Hunt/status/1151853221461286914):

> I missed votes today because I thought I was slipped and it turns out I was not.Apologies to my colleagues & Whips Office.

**What does "slipped" mean in this context?** It seems to be an unusual and possibly specialist meaning - I can't find any meaning in the usual dictionary sources which covers this. It might be a term from UK parliamentary jargon, or [as one person on Twitter claims](https://twitter.com/RKemb/status/1151855784332017666) from UK private school slang.

Comment: IMHO - thought he got an excused absence

Comment: I think you might have more luck on the Politics SE. There are a few users there who are very knowledgeable about UK parliamentary procedure and Westminster politics in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Politics.SE

Comment: @JJJ As mentioned in the question, I'm not sure if it's political jargon or private school jargon as claimed on Twitter. (And if you think the latter is implausible, [allow me to introduce you to the UK Conservative party](https://news.sky.com/video/brexit-jacob-rees-mogg-drops-a-public-school-burn-against-fellow-tory-mps-11676685).) So it might very well have been off-topic entirely on Politics SE, but it's definitely about the usage of the English language.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - it appears that the answer in based entirely on political issues.

Comment: @user240918 Yes, but questions don't become on-topic or off-topic based on their answers. Also, another site's scope is irrelevant to deciding whether a question is on-topic or off-topic for *this* site.

Comment: @user240918 But that's not clear from the question itself, until after it's answered. Anyway [being political doesn't make a question off-topic here, per se](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/467461/87724).

Comment: @user240918 It's a question of language, what that word means. Even if it needs some explanation about politics, it is still a language question.

Comment: @user240918 There is absolutely no doubt whatsoever, in any way, shape or form, that this question is ***completely on-topic*** here. The meaning of a given word in a given context, not findable in standard dictionaries, is pretty much the most on-topic thing you could possibly ask about on ELU, regardless of whether that given context happens to be the topic of other SE sites as well.

Comment: @user240918 - "Entirely political?" I don't see what's "political" about converting a noun like _slip_ (as in _absentee slip_) into a verb. That sounds more like a matter of language than politics. In this case, it happens to have used by a member of parliament, but this verbification could just as easily be used in a school, at a bank, or on a football team. I don't think this question belongs on [Politics.se] any more than [this other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497748/where-does-the-term-physical-come-from) belongs on [sports.se].

Comment: @Randal'Thor Lest one be forever wondering whether *private school slang* 
means the private slang of schools or the slang of
private schools, not to mention whether *UK private school slang*
means the British slang of private schools, the private
British slang of schools, the private slang of British schools, the slang
of the schools of British privates, the slang of the schools of private
Britons, the privied slang of the schools of the Britons, or the school slang of British privies, might
I peradventure tempt you into doing us the honor of editing in a hyphen or two here and there?

Comment: @tchrist Upon carefully measured ambiguity I thrive, provided the true meaning is clear at least from a soupçon of çontext. Furthermore, adding hyphens to usually-unhyphenated phrases in their phrasal-adjective form, although presumably a practice well supported among the highest echelons of Anglophones such as yourself, has always rendered me a mite twitchy.

Answer (score 9):

From "[Whips and their Work](http://www.w4mp.org/library/parliament-guides/whos-who/whips-and-their-work/)":

> A three-line Whip is essential and an MP frankly has no choice but to attend unless he or she has cleared their absence with their whip in advance by handing in an absence request slip with a full explanation and a pleading manner.

Hence, I presume that Jeremy Hunt believed that he was excused from attending said particular vote having completed an absence request slip (or having had one of his staff complete the slip for him).

For non-UK readers, a "Whip" is an MP (Member of Parliament) charged with ensuring that fellow MPs from the same political party attend certain votes.  The most important votes will be underlined three times on the weekly sheets distributed to MPs, and are hence called "three-line whips".  The term originates in hunting, where a "whipper-in" is "a huntsman's assistant who keeps the hounds from straying by driving them back with the whip into the main body of the pack" (from OED).

Comment: The mismumblejumbled pronouns manifest in *unless **he or she** has cleared **their** absence with **their** whip* are hilarious postchildren for a blanket ban on their or their utilizationages.